# How to find [**] in a regex statement so I can use multi_line_start_pattern for aws cloudwatch agent

Tags: regex, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a log stream that looks like this:

```
[**] [1:10000001:1] ICMP test [**]
[Priority: 0] 
12/12-05:35:39.933931 172.31.12.xxx -> 172.31.2.xxx
ICMP TTL:64 TOS:0x0 ID:375 IpLen:20 DgmLen:84 DF
Type:8  Code:0  ID:14832   Seq:3927  ECHO

[**] [1:10000001:1] ICMP test [**]
[Priority: 0] 
12/12-05:35:40.933854 172.31.12.106 -> 172.31.2.207
ICMP TTL:64 TOS:0x0 ID:417 IpLen:20 DgmLen:84 DF
Type:8  Code:0  ID:14832   Seq:3928  ECHO
```

I want to use the cloudwatch agent to create a single event from a multi line event.

Per the docs:

```
multi_line_start_pattern – Specifies the pattern for identifying the start of a log message. A log message is made of a line that matches the pattern and any following lines that don't match the pattern.
If you omit this field, multi-line mode is disabled, and any line that begins with a non-whitespace character closes the previous log message and starts a new log message.
```

How do I create a regex that will find if [**] exists.  E.g.

```
"multi_line_start_pattern": "\\[\\*\\*\\]\\"
```

For for the pattern:

```
[**] ANYTHING [**]
```

From what I gather it will suffice to find the existence of [**] to find the start of a multiline event.

So what is the regex pattern to find [**] or better [**] ANYTHING [**]?  I dont know regex

Thanks

Comment: Like this: https://regex101.com/r/M5OmrS/1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, though it may differ depending on your language.

```
\[\*\*\].+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/^\[\*\*\]([\s\w\[\]\:])*?\[\*\*\]/gm
```

Exmplaination:  `^` means, line must start with the following. then `**` then some space bracket texts, then `**` again. `g` means search the whole document, `m` means multiline